# Why does rethrowing an exception discards the information given by 'what()'?

Tags: c++, exception, g++

I'm using MinGW gcc (or g++) 7.1.0 on Windows 10.

Normally, throwing an `std::runtime_error` shows information like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  MESSAGE

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

But the following code only shows the last two lines, and the `what()` information is lost:

```
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    try {
        throw runtime_error("MESSAGE");
    } catch (...) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

So the code above only outputs:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

The same thing happens if I replace `...` with `const exception&`, `const runtime_error&` (or without `const`, without `&`, or without both).

As I know, `throw;` rethrows the current caught exception. So why isn't `what()` shown?

Comment: What makes you think that rethrowing exception discards the information given by 'what()'? You never inspect what `what()` returns after rethrowing. `This application has requested` message is shown because you uncaught exception caused program to be terminated. `what()`  is not supposed to be printed.

Comment: Blame Windows. http://ideone.com/UVRna0

Comment: @VTT Maybe it's something about rewording... I know the information IS in the exception object, and manually outputing the information does work,  but isn't it simpler if `what()` is automatically shown like normal?

Comment: @VTT what() *is* normally printed.

Comment: @n.m. what() *may* be printed

Comment: @n.m. I'd totally upvote anything containing *Blame Windows*

Comment: In my experiments with Windows, nothing whatsoever is printed to the standard output, whether an exception is rethrown or the original one is propagated out of `main`. I'm not using Windows 10 though.

Comment: @VTT yes, but the wording of the question seems to imply that it is sometimes printed and sometimes not, depending on how exactly the exception was thrown (this may or may not be true).

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that rethrowing exception discards the information given by 'what()'? You never inspect what `what()` returns after rethrowing. `This application has requested...` message is shown because you uncaught exception caused program to be terminated. `what()` content is not supposed to be printed automatically.

You can print value return by `what()` without any problem:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            throw ::std::runtime_error("MESSAGE");
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch(::std::exception const & exception)
    {
        ::std::cout << exception.what() << ::std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `what()` is intended to be printed manually, I'd take it. Well this seems a little bit tiring.

Comment: @TRCYX notice that not catching exceptions and letting program just crash cause of uncaught exception may have other troublesome consequences, such as calls to destructors being omitted and no proper cleanup performed.

Comment: Indeed. Should not do this in a real program, but still feel a little strange with these toy programs.